# Error when extending user django model and define permissions for each model

Tags: python, django

I would like to have 2 types of users, NormalUsers and ArtistUser, with different permissions for each one:

- NormalUsers: create playlist
- ArtistUser: add songs, albums and create playlist too.

I've tried extending the django user model and my codes is this:

models.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class ArtistUser(models.Model):
  id_artista = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
  user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  is_artist = models.BooleanField(default=True)
  name = models.TextField(max_length=50)

class NormalUser(models.Model):
  id_user = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
  user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  is_artist = models.BooleanField(default=False)
  name = models.TextField(max_length=50)

class Album(models.Model):
  id_album = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
  name_album = models.TextField(max_length=50)
  artista = models.ForeignKey(ArtistUser)

class Song(models.Model):
  id_song = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
  name_song = models.TextField(max_length=50)
  artist = models.ForeignKey(ArtistUser)
  album = models.ForeignKey(Album)

class Playlist(models.Model):
  id_playlist = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
  name_playlist = models.TextField(max_length=50)
  user = models.ForeignKey(User)
  songs = models.ManyToManyField(Song)
```

Someone could help me with the code to get this.

Thank in advance.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: OperationalError at /admin/idjango_practice/album/
no such table: idjango_practice_album. Diferents models appears in the localhost/admin but don't in the database. It's probably doesn't code error and data base connect error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED:

Easier than have different user, i add a user to the group, it depends on the role, then each group has different permissions

```
if data['normal_user'] == True:
    normal_user_group = Group.objects.get(name='normal_user')
    normal_user_group.user_set.add(user)

if data['artist_user'] == True:
    artist_user_group = Group.objects.get(name='artist_user')
    artist_user_group.user_set.add(user)
```